# Linux distro running entirely on Wayland (no X11)?

Tags: linux, x11, distribution-choice, wayland

As of 2017, is there a distro that doesn't have X11 server installed and instead uses Wayland? I don't want to boot into text-mode, I want to boot into graphical mode without X11.

Comment: It will be really difficult to find *any* distribution that doesn't boot into text on fbdev first, and *then* starts Wayland.

Comment: @dirkt true, but distros using Plymouth switch to a graphical progress bar *very* quickly on modern systems — so the impression is that you go straight from EFI to Grub (if it’s used) to a graphical boot to the login screen.

Answer (score 9):

[Fedora 25](https://getfedora.org/) uses Wayland by default, although it still has `Xwayland` to support all the X11 clients.

There is an X11 server too, for X11 sessions if necessary. But the default setup doesn’t use it at all.

Comment: If I delete XWayland, will it still boot?

Comment: I’ll let you try that... `gdm` and the GNOME packages end up depending on the Xwayland package, so I doubt it. Even if it boots, you won’t be able to *run* much, many applications in Fedora are still X clients, not Wayland clients.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [RebeccaBlackOS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rebeccablackos/). Quote:

> The latest ISO now has a login manager for Wayland, and now it has removed X from the startup path of the system.

Last time I tested it (about a year ago) it offered different Wayland compositors, some with and some without Xwayland.